# Rotate ImageView in widget

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I'm creating a widget where I need to rotate an ImageView. The ImageView resides insides a layout which in turn is described in a RemoteView. Is this possible? In my regular application Activity gained a reference to the ImageView using findViewById() and then calling setRotate(), but as RemoteView isn't an activity findViewById() isn't available.

I can see that it has been done before in this app: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lanteanstudio.compass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `RemoteViews`, then you cannot directly change the visible View itself, as there is no way of getting a reference to it -- a `RemoteViews` object generally runs in a different process (in the case of the widgets on the Homescreen this is true - the widgets run in the Homescreen process, not your own).

Instead you need to create a new RemoteViews with the image rotated - you need to rotate the bitmap before setting it to the `ImageView`.

Then get an instance of `AppWidgetManager`, and call `manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView)`.

Comment: As far as I can see that gives the following error:
05-12 08:48:01.540: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(356): android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.widget.ImageView can't use method with RemoteViews: setRotation(float)

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure if `setRotation` was `Remoteable` - apparently not. In that case you might need to rotate the actual Bitmap before calling `setImageBitmap`

Comment: Glad to hear it - updated my answer to reflect that rotating the bitmap itself is the right route should anyone look at this question in future.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day on this... I found the following code to work for my weather app widget to indicate wind direction.

- R.drawable.arrow is png in my drawable folder
- windDeg is an int obtained from openweathermap.org
- R.id.wind_direction is an ImageView

  ```
   val bmpOriginal: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.applicationContext.resources,         R.drawable.arrow)
   val bmpResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.width, bmpOriginal.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
   val tempCanvas = Canvas(bmpResult)
   tempCanvas.rotate(windDeg.toFloat(), bmpOriginal.width / 2.toFloat(), bmpOriginal.height / 2.toFloat())
   tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0f, 0f, null)
   views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.wind_direction, bmpResult)
  ```